# Exception when trying to navigate to another fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-jetpack-navigation

I recently started exploring with the Nav component and I stumbled into this `Fragment HomeContainerFragment{e1561bc} (156e8ba6-f284-4c85-a4bb-82a63069888b)}notassociated with a fragment manager.` Huh? But that's a fragment. I could even navigate to it using fragment transaction replace. The error points to the findNavController:

```
NavDirections navDirections = LoginFragmentDirections.actionLoginFragmentToHomeContainerFragment();

NavHostFragment.findNavController(HomeContainerFragment.newInstance()).navigate(navDirections)
```

This `HomeContainerFragment.newInstance()` returns this `new HomeContainerFragment()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I misunderstood the argument for `findNavController`. I thought it was supposed to be the fragment that was going to replace the current one. I was wrong. It's supposed to be the *current* fragment, not the next one.

So changing it to: `findNavController(this)` fixed it.